# How to scroll to top of parent iframe pressing a button inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

The page is from eBay listings.
This is the main sctructure:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/" />
</body>
```

The main html location is ebay.co.uk and the iframe is from another domain.

Inside of iframe i have a button `#totop` and on press I want the main html to scroll to top of page, not the iframe content.

This is possible?

Comment: You cannot do this when the domain's are different it's a security policy, unless they have the [messaging api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) setup to allow for it

Comment: Do you have access to both frames so you can add javascript code in both of them?

Comment: No. I only have access to iframe.

Comment: The only way to communicate between frames from different domains is `postMessage` [see MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage). But it requires parent frame to handle messages you send from child frame.

Comment: there is also a gototop button on main html, you can check any eBay product for that. If I can't scroll with a js, than maybe can connect somehow to that button to start his scrolling function?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible if you don't have control over the parent site (in this case ebay.co.uk). Protocols, domains, and ports must match if you wan't target your scripts to parent site.

If those frames were using the same domain, this would work:

```
<button id="totop" onclick="window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)">
  Scroll parent to top
</button>
```

If you had control over the parent site's (ebay.co.uk) web server, you could create a reverse proxy to fool the system. For example in Apache httpd you could create a reverse proxy like this:

```
ProxyPass /iframe http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com
ProxyPassReverse /iframe http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com
```

And set the iframe's src to http://ebay.co.uk/iframe

```
<iframe src="http://ebay.co.uk/iframe"></iframe>
```

This would allow you to target scripts to ebay.co.uk from the iframe.

Anyway, in this case it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>very long content very long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long content
      very long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery
      very long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long content
      very long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long content
      very long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long content
      very long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long content
      very long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long content
      very long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long content
      very long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long contentvery long content
    </h1>

    <iframe src="frame.html"></iframe>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/co4FoQVjrF2TmXZy0oNP?p=preview)

Comment: it's not working, I think because it's not same domain